# In 2s complement floating point what is wrong with the leading 11?

Tags: floating-point, binary

I think I get why 01 is good because it does not waste any significant digits and this why 00 is not good. But not sure what the problem with 11 is and why the most significant bits must be 10 for a negative 2s complement float to be normalised.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear.  In particular, can you say what you mean by "2s complement floating point"?

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear, but I believe Mellyo is asking about non-standard signed significand + exponent formats.  For simplicity, let's consider eight-bit twos-complement significands.

All positive numbers have significands of the form `b0xxxxxxx`.  We say a significand is *normalized* if it has the full representable precision, so the normalized positive significands have the form `b01xxxxxx`, and represent seven significant bits; interpreted as integers, these significands have values in the range [64,127].

All negative numbers have significands of the form `b1xxxxxxx`.  What is a normalized negative significand?  Precise the negation of a normalized positive significand; we need to be able to represent significands with integer values in the range [-127,-64], which have the following bit patterns:

```
b10000001   -127
b10000010   -126
...
b10111111   -65
b11000000   -64
```

Note that things are a little weird with the edge cases for these formats; -64 has the bit pattern `b11000000`, which we may want to exclude, and -128 has the bit pattern `b10000000` which we may want to include, so sometimes people slide the range of significands for negative values.  Ones-complement and sign-magnitude are more natural representations for floating-point significands for this reason (because they have ranges symmetric around zero).

Comment: Yes sorry very non standard. I is on the AQA A level for learning floats. I simply state that a float is normalised when the mantissa has 01 or 10 in left most bits. I think what you are explaining is the same system so 0101 could be 0.5+0.125 or 1011 would be -1+0.25+0.125. Obviously both need an exponent too. I still not sure if yo have answered why we exclude 11 it he left most bits for a negative though? Why is that not nor asked?

Comment: For the same reason we exclude 00 with positive significands; those significands have less than full precision.